# org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller umlauts and special characters

Tags: java, jaxb, jaxb2

How can I marshal java string object that contain umlauts by using 
org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller ?
I have java string like `Alizée`.
After marshalling with using Jaxb2Marshaller i get `AlizÃ©e` xml string.

Answer (score 5):

This can be right, but you are vieving the marshalled XML with the wrong charset (you view UTF-8 as ISO-8859-1/extended ASCII).

I would double-check character encodings and that you are viewing the marshalled XML with the correct encoding.

Example: **é** is in UTF-8 represented by two bytes: `0xC3` `0xA9`  http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00e9/index.htm

These two bytes, represented in for example ISO-8859-1 will read:

- `0xC3`: **Ã** http://ascii-table.com/info.php?u=x00C3
- `0xA9`: **©** http://ascii-table.com/info.php?u=x00A9

If you create a text file containing **é** and save it as `UTF-8`. Re-open the file but choose encoding `ISO-8859-1` and you will see the same.

Comment: what you mean "double-check character encodings"?

Comment: If JAXB2 generates XML with UTF-8-enocded characters, you should make sure it is not viewed/treated as data with another encoding. That means that your terminal encoding should be UTF-8 (if you print the XML out to your terminal). The one who receive/parse the XML should also treat it as UTF-8. I suspect that if you make JAXB2 unmarshal the very same XML, everything will be Ok.

Comment: :) no i do not view my xml in terminal. i view xml into browser with utf-8. I need to mask each of umlauts into &#xxx; format before rendering/marshalling. This WORKS!

Comment: response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); - fixed my problem without any masking!